# GATSBY problem with gatsby pages updating state

Tags: gatsby

How do I fix this, the current page is a page that is created by createPage in gatsby-node.js which fetched from contentful. Please hepl!
Can't open the sidebar menu.

[image: here is the image]

Comment: Can you show us your gatsby-node.js code and your template page code that is rendering this page

Comment: Here it is [link](https://i.imgur.com/XUslar0.png)

Comment: and also, the images won't load